# Укажите ошибки в следующих предложениях

Tags: грамотная-речь

Если говорить кратко, то мне нужно найти все ошибки в нескольких предложениях и объяснить, почему это является ошибками.

1.Зачем мне быть подобной тебе, которая готова своих.. "недо-друзей" высмеивать на форуме?

2.Ты готов оправдать удаление своей темы за счёт моих личных взаимоотношений? Интересно звучит.

3. Упомянание моего возраста в теме лишь доказывает то, что у тебя попросту нету аргументов своей невиновности.